# How do you generally handle preview of markdown content?

Tags: website-design, content, preview

I'm rendering a lot of markdown in my applications e.g. a forum with an overview of posts that render a preview of that markdown.

How does stackexchange handle preview of markdown?

Take for example this page
[image]

As you can see the headings are disturbing the reading flow. But I have no idea what to do with them?

Render them as bold text regardless of level? Render them like normal text? Exclude headings from the text?

How does stackexchange handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are hoping for in an answer here. And also, why are you specifically asking about what StackExchange does? Aren't you more interested in what the general best solution would be? Please clarify what your actual question is here. If it's specific to StackExchange then you should ask on the [Meta site](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead of the main one.

Comment: @JonW I'm interested in best practices as this has to be a somewhat common problem from a UX perspective. I am referring to stackexchange implementation because I assume they adhere to best practices and have knowledge and UX experience behind their implementation.